# How to setup Domain Controller in Windows 7?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have Windows 7 Ultimate and some few other XP Pro machines. I would like to setup Domain Controller in some sort of way, (Without having a Server OS I know this is a long shot ) so that my XP machines can join the domain.

I am looking for workarounds or any other feasible method without me having to spend money on additional software (but if its little I would not mind much)

I suppose many power users here would have done this through a hack or some third party software. Thanks

**EDIT:** What I would like to achieve is, first of all, centralised users accounts management. This would be more useful, because I run certain software like SVN which can take advantage of AD. And Next I would surely love to have Group Policy management etc. (This is a nice to have)

Comment: This is actually a small pet-peeve of mine - centralized user accounts makes a lot of sense in a modern computerized home, but not even Windows Home Server uses it - it makes no sense ^^

Comment: I'd suggest you add more detail to your question in order to get better quality answers, specifically what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want centralised user accounts? Or do you want to play around with a proper Active Directory environment, i.e. Group Policies, Software Deployment, etc.?

Comment: @Graeme, I have edited the question

Answer (score 5):

There's no hack or third party software. If you want an Active Directory environment, you need a server edition of Windows.

Comment: you need windows server to setup a domain controller in Windows at least.

Comment: @aduljr, isn't that what Graeme just said?

Comment: yes, tired answer. I did make a suggestion to use linux

Answer (score 2):

The entire Active Directory structure isn't exactly something that you can "hack". If you want, you can set up an open source directory service, but I doubt that's your intent. Perhaps  [389 Directory Server](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/) or [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/)? Of course, there's that little annoyanace factor of not having GPOs to play with.

If you want to use Active Directory for test purposes you can always get a trial of Windows Server. Just don't use it for any production purposes, of course.

You can make a poor man's AD with something like the pstools suite. PSExec can be used and abused in so many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Now you could take a crack at linux and setup samba as a domain controller or tale look at a appliance like this one.

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller

which may suit your needs. It just runs on a VM.